# AdMob Mediation Test?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have implemented iAd and AdMob into my app only to realize that iAd will shut down soon. Many posts have been made about iAd not showing after submission/review. So now I have decided on inmobi and some other networks. I would like to implement these using AdMob Mediation. AdMob runs perfectly and I am getting test Ads for both banner and interstitial.

I have followed this AdMob Mediation Guide and somewhere in there towards the end is this:

> There is no need to write additional code to create ad views from each
>   ad network. Mediation invokes each ad network's adapter and SDK as
>   necessary to create ads

So ALL I have to do to receive Ads from other networks would be to :

1.Sign up for other networks (i.e MillenialMedia, inmobi etc)
2.Download other network's SDK Download Network Adapters
3.ADD both the SDK and Adapter to my XCode Project From my AdMob Ad Units page,
4.ADD said networks as sources using their own ID and maybe play around with the CPM a little
5.NO extra code needed?

So as long as I know that my AdMob is working, theoretically if I have followed the above steps theres no need for any extra code to receive ads from other networks? Do I have to do anything with AdID?

I have referred to other similar questions but Im not getting much out of them. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> So as long as I know that my AdMob is working, theoretically if I have followed the above steps theres no need for any extra code to receive ads from other networks?

You are correct. You just need to add their SDK/Adapter, configure their SDK as needed (some networks require you to initialize their SDK in AppDelegate for example), and Admob will handle the rest.

One way that you can test network integration is to create a new interstitial advertisement with mediation and only add the network you'd like to test. Then, set that network's CPM to $10.00 or even $100.00 and it will be shown first in the mediation waterfall every time.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Admob has recently partnered with a few networks to go SDK free.

Basically when adding these networks you don't need to interrogate an SDK. However you still need to sign up for an account on these partner networks.